# The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int

Tags: java, operators

PROBLEM:

I'm attempting to pull the value of a boolean via sharedpreferences however everytime I attempt to use the value I'm getting a compiler error stating the operator is undefined for the argument type. I'm not sure why this is occuring - I believe I've converted the time boolean to a string - then I should be able to use that as a value to multiply by to get my time value:

SOURCE:

```
    String PREF = "prefs";
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    boolean name = prefs.getBoolean("name", true); 
    boolean code = prefs.getBoolean("corename", true);
    boolean time = prefs.getBoolean("time", true);
    boolean ssid = prefs.getBoolean("restricted", true);

    String killtime = String.valueOf(time);




    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Rules.this, KillTimer.class);
    PendingIntent pintent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(Rules.this, 0, intent2,
            0);
    AlarmManager alarm2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            killtime * 1000, pintent2); // error is thrown here
```

Comment: at which line you got the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to multiply a `String` and an `int` together.  That doesn't make sense.  Then again, the value that the `String` has wouldn't make sense if coerced into an `int` anyway - it's either 1 or 0, which could be more clearly illustrated (interestingly enough) with a ternary statement.

```
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
        time ? 1000 : 0, pintent2);
```